# Error while running GCM sample app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I tried to run sample application provided by google for GCM.

www.developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

I followed all the instructions but got following error shown in [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcudS.png)

Edit 1:

API key copied from developer console
and
API key used in my project

check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbPU4.png)

as you can see that both API keys are same

Comment: As per the error that you are receiving, it seems that you have not provided the correct api key. Can you please check if you have replaced the api key properly?

Comment: In GcmSender.java have you replaced the API_KEY with the value that you have for your GCM Project?

Comment: i had done that correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. In [developers guidelines](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) the instructions is:

> When the sample application loads on your device, run the following
> gradle command to send a notification to all registered app instances:
>
> Linux/Mac:
>
> ./gradlew run -Pmsg="message"
>
> Windows:
>
> .\gradlew.bat run -Pmsg="message"

But each time I run the gradle command the same error happened.

Finally instead of running the gradle command, I run `GcmSender.java` itself in android studio and it worked correctly and notifaction appeared on my device.

Note that before running `GcmSender.java` you must edit run configuration and pass your message as `Program arguments`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable called API_KEY in GcmSender and you are not using the correct key. Follow the steps below to get the correct API key.

- Step 1: Go to your Google Developer Console.
- Step 2: Create a new project.
- Step 3: Click 'Google Cloud Messaging' API on the overview screen.
- Step 4: Click 'Enable'
- Step 5: Go to 'Credentials and create a new API key for Android.
- Step 6: Take the API key and copy paste into GcmSender.

Comment: i already completed that step and in developer console it was showing default app

Comment: Alright are you sending to a device token or is the device subscribed to a topic?

Comment: i didn't know that part. just starting with GCM and didn't changed anything in sample app

Comment: I get the same error message as you are "Please ensure that API_KEY has been replaced by the server API key, and that the device's registration token is correct (if specified)." when i intentionally use the wrong key. You can try using my modified version of gcmSender instead, see this link https://github.com/CarlOhlsson/gcmTemplateServer

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and i found that i was using the wrong API Key. USE Server API key that has been provided by GCM instead of Dummy API Key(API_Key). Hope you will succeed. Best of Luck!!